Bootstrap 5 Dropdown Submenu Not Expanding
I am trying to implement a dropdown menu in Bootstrap 5. The dropdown menu appears, but the submenu items do not expand when clicked. Here is my code:
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.jsp">Green Garden</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="main.jsp">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="main.jsp">List</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">member</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item active" href="login.jsp">sign in</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="join.jsp">sign up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="jumbotron" style="padding-top: 20px">
                <form method="post" action="loginAction.jsp">
                    <h3>Sign in to your Account!</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="userID" maxlength="20">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="userPassword" maxlength="20">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="로그인">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz4fnFO9gybBogGzS1nQZVXT1mo/xWOVvBMEFJlHq2BOsvI5g5EnnxI3Ns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+3oY2amUK7B1o3J6tYf0XK72smfY6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>


Problem: The dropdown menu labeled "member" appears correctly, but the submenu items (sign in, sign up) do not expand when clicked.
What I've Tried:
Ensured that the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript are properly included.
Verified the structure of the dropdown menu.
Expected Behavior: When I click on the "member" dropdown, I expect to see the submenu items (sign in, sign up) expand and be clickable.
Can someone help me identify what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Just add this script at the end of the body tag:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


Thank you for answering my question but as you can see, i already did..

@Cathy Okay, Try with this script <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
